# error handling when developing PHP application

Tags: php, macos, apache

When I have a runtime error during PHP development instead of getting a line number (like in Java) I simply get a HTTP 500 internal server error.

[image]

In order to get an idea of what line the error is happening I have to comment out each line of code until the application runs. Is this normal practice for a PHP developer or am I missing something.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

I am developing locally on Mac OS 10.7 Apache Web server.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', true);`

Comment: You need to check the web-server's error log to find more information about the 500 error.

Comment: Thanks ceejayoz, ini_set('display_errors', true); fixed the issue

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why the downvotes, but here is the solution. Thanks ceejayoz.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```